# OCIEnvCreate failed to create environment handle after installing oracle_fdw

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle-fdw

I'm want use Postgresql 9.3 in CentOS 7 and add extention oracle_fdw.
but when use this extenstion i get error

OCIEnvCreate failed to create environment handle after installing oracle_fdw.

my roadmap:

- install postgresql 9.3 from postgres rpm.
- install oracle instant client 11.2g with rpm files from oracle site.
- install  oracle-instant client11.2-basic & oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus  &
  oracle-instantclient11.2-devel.

I use this question : [OCIEnvCreate failed to create environment handle after installing oracle_fdw](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14327/ocienvcreate-failed-to-create-environment-handle-after-installing-oracle-fdw)

my variables :

```
/etc/profile :
export PG_HOME=/usr/pgsql-9.3
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PG_HOME/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME:$PG_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

tnsnames.ora :

I created `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`:

```
BEH =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.18.102.107)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

When I use the sqlplus command line, I can connect using `sqlplus user/pass@BEH` and can select from tables.

Using `psql` in my Postgres database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw; 
      resutlt : Query returned successfully.

CREATE SERVER beh FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw OPTIONS (dbserver 'AMI_BEH');
   OR
   CREATE SERVER beh FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw OPTIONS (dbserver '//172.18.102.107:1521/ORCL');  
      result : Query returned successfully.

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER beh OPTIONS (user 'ORACLE_USER',password 'ORACLE_PASS');
      result : Query returned successfully.

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE bl
   ("OLD_DYDJ" character varying(20) ,
    "DYDJ" character varying(20) ,
    "MC" character varying(128) )
   SERVER beh
   OPTIONS (table 'DYDJ_DY');
      result : Query returned successfully.

SELECT * FROM bl;
      result : error connecting to Oracle: OCIEnvCreate failed to create environment handle.
```

I checked that I can use `sqlplus` as the `postgres` user (`su - postgres`) and I can connect to oracle with the `sqlplus` command.

I found this link http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.general/166914 , so I checked:

```
SELECT pg_backend_pid(); result : 3854
ps -p3854 -oppid=        result : 1902
cat /proc/1902/environ | xargs -0 -n1
   result : 
      PG_GRANDPARENT_PID=1
      USER=postgres
      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
      PWD=/
      PGLOCALEDIR=/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/locale
      LANG=en_US.UTF-8
      PGSYSCONFDIR=/etc/sysconfig/pgsql
      SHLVL=1
      HOME=/var/lib/pgsql
      LOGNAME=postgres
      PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
      _=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres
```

Comment: try to execute `lsof -p 3854`. Theoretically instant client's libclntsh.so should work even without ORACLE_HOME set, but at least you should have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set. Is it possible that your postresql was started via init.d/rc.d script and necessary env variables were not exported? Try to stop postgresql and start it manually from command line.

Comment: my centos install on minimal mode. i use _lsof -p 3854 | grep libcln_ then my reult is _postgres 3854 postgres  mem    REG  253,1  52761218  67151515 /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1_ . next i check again my LD_LIBRARY_PATH with echo this my result is : _/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64:/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib:_ 
<br>
in centos 7 services start at _/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postgresql-9.3.service_ . @ibre5041

Answer (score 1):

If you install from an rpm then it's installed as a service.

If you start postgresql from a custom script as user postgres then the process will catch the environment variables but if you start postgresql as a service it won't.

You should look for how to pass environment variables to systemd (or sysv) services.

I used [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service) example for systemd services. CentOS 7 uses systemd.

In */etc/systemd/system* create *postgresql.service.d* directory and place inside a file *orafdw.conf* with your environment variables and restart (not sure about only reload). Make sure the directory name match your postgresql service name.

Something like...

```
[Service]
Environment=ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/home
Environment=TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/tnsadmin
...
(All the variables you want)
```

Regards,

Walter